# Matlab: How can formatSpec work with '?

Tags: matlab

I want to write a cell array in a (m-)file in a way that it is interpreted as a cell: cell elements quoted 'element' and separated with comma and blank. To archive this formatSpec should handle ' which it can not directly: formatSpec = ''%s', ' is not working (same as strrep(S, '§', ''')). Is there a way to mark ' like with \ in regular expressions? Here a code example where ' is substituted with §:

```
 Pop_plus = {'(-1./z)', '(1./(z.^-2))', '((z-1)./(z+1))', '(((z+1)./z)./2)', '(z+sqrt((z.^2)-1))', '(1./(4.*(z.^2)-1))'};

 Pop_plus_out_path_m = ...\Pop_plus.m;
 fileID = fopen(Pop_plus_out_path_m, 'wt');
 formatSpec = '%s';
 L1 = {'F = {'};
 fprintf(fileID,formatSpec,L1{1});
 formatSpec = '§%s§, ';
 for i = 1:numel(Pop_plus)-1
      fprintf(fileID,formatSpec,Pop_plus{i});                            
 end
 formatSpec = '§%s§';
 fprintf(fileID,formatSpec,Pop_plus{numel(Pop_plus)});
 L2 = {'};'};
 formatSpec = '%s';
 fprintf(fileID,formatSpec,L2{1});
 fclose(fileID);


 result: F = {§(-1./z)§, §(1./(z.^-2))§, §((z-1)./(z+1))§, §(((z+1)./z)./2)§, §(z+sqrt((z.^2)-1))§, §(1./(4.*(z.^2)-1))§};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't just an issue when using it as a format specifier, this is an issue whenever you are attempting to define a character array. You need to escape `'` with another `'` when trying to use it within a character array.

```
'''string'
%   'string
```

For your specific example, you could create your format specification

```
formatSpec = '''%s''';
```

Comment: Thanks! Works perfect!

Comment: @GünterBachelier If this worked for you, please consider marking it as an accepted solution